# AppBarToggleButton - False Check Issue

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, togglebutton, commandbar

I have an issue with AppBarToggleButton.
When the user touch it and drag the finger outside the button and release it, the button stays in the "Pressed" visual state, so it appears that the button has been checked, but it doesn't fires any event, it only really gets checked if the user click it again.

Comment: Sounds like it may be worth reporting as a bug.

Comment: I will not be able to publish my app with this bug.
Do you know where it's appropriate to report bugs like that?

Comment: I think generally the dev community forums over at microsoft will do, or at least get you direction from MS as to where specifically to do it.

Comment: Exactly my problem too and unfortunatly no solutions yet ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported that on MSDN forums, and they filed this bug to fix it.

Here's the link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79bd05b4-1bb7-4d32-af62-713db580f80f/appbartogglebutton-issue-false-checking?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required

Unfortunately, there's no way to fix that inside our apps for now according to them. I hope that this gets fixed fast, but I'm afraid that it's get fixed only on future versions of the OS and our apps works with unexpected behavior on actual versions.